# How to convert a bytes object to a raw bytes object (for use in regex)?

Tags: python, byte

I am using a regular expression in my code to find an invalid sequence in a bytes object in Python 3.0. Right now the regex is hard coded, but I would like to be able to build this regex on the fly. My problem is that I don't know how to make a raw bytes object out of a bytes object.

Here is the hard coded version:

```
re.search(rb'\\[^{}|]', packet_data, re.MULTILINE)
```

I have verified that it DOES NOT work if I simply change `rb'\\[^{}|]'` to `b'\\[^{}|]'`, which means that I cannot build up the regular expression just as a concatenation of a bunch of bytes (b'...') objects - I need it to be in the form of a raw bytes (rb'...').

I've checked the type of both `rb'foo'` and `b'foo'`, but Python just says that both are `<class 'bytes'>`.

I know that this has to do with how the backslash is handled/represented differently in raw bytes vs bytes objects. In fact, *this* does work: `b'\\\\[^{}|]'`. My problem is that I may not always use the backslash, I may use a different character in its place, so I would like an encoder that will do expansion the for me.

Edit: I do understand that "raw bytes" is not a type. What I am looking for is a way to format a bytes object to get the `rb'...'` representation. We can do this with Strings using  `str.encode('raw_unicode_escape')`. What is the bytes equivalent?

Comment: There's no such thing as a raw bytes object. "raw" is not a type of object, it's just a different way of parsing strings in source code.

Comment: @Barmar I understand this, but I need to build up a raw representation of a sequence of bytes for the dynamic regular expression. My problem is that simply using the normal bytes syntax, b'...' does not work whereas rb'...' does. I can use rb'...' for a static regex, but I don't how to pass in an expression built up of bytes objects in a form that re wants. I would like to avoid having to manually escape slashes if they are found in my dynamic regex.

Comment: You can concatenate byte strings that were created using `rb'...'`. `rb'foo' + rb'bar'`

Comment: " I would like an encoder that will do expansion the for me".  `b'\\'` is a single backslash of string length 1.  There's nothing to expand.  Just append a backslash.  Raw strings are a way to enter string that contain literal backslashes, but due to the parsing rules `rb'\'` is a syntax error, and `rb'\\'` returns `b'\\\\'` (two literal backslashes, string length 2).

Comment: @MarkTolonen Maybe this is where I am getting confused. In the static case, my regex is `rb'\\[^{}|]'`. The parts that are dynamic are the backslash, curly braces, and pipe character.  So, if I replace the backslash with, say, a dash my regex becomes `rb'-[^{}|]'`. I don't need to double the dash because it isn't used as an escape character in the bytes object. Each of these characters resides in its own variable, so what I really want to be able to do is `regex = char1 + b'^[' + char2 + char3 + b']'`. Is there a way to auto-escape special characters in the concatenated bytes object?

Comment: Yes, `char2 = b'\\'`.  That is *one* character, just like `char2 = b'-'` is one character.  Then set `regex` just as you've shown.